# How to create memory pressure and analyze various trends /proc/pressure/memory from that (python/bash)

Tags: python, linux, memory, kernel, pressure

From stack overflow I found :

```
a = []
while True:
    print len(a)
    a.append(' ' * 10**6)
```

But this ate up memory so quickly in real world memory pressure happens due to slow leakage in memory. I do not have any stress tool access. I tried doing dd if , but I could not see any spikes in /proc/pressure/memory

This assignment is so interesting for me but I am stuck with how to implement real time memory pressure to study the trend of /proc/pressure/memory

Comment: Just add a suitably long sleep to your Python loop?

Comment: Thank you for answering, yes I did try with sleep of 1sec but I see no spike in /proc/pressure/memory and also the free -m seems to be having fluctuations when I introduce sleep. a = [] while True: print len(a) a.append(' ' * 10**6) time.sleep(1)

Comment: You can calculate the rise in memory usage by dividing the string size by the sleep time. For example, since you allocate 1MB every 1 second, then memory usage goes up by a very slow 1MB/s. If you want to allocate more quickly, e.g. 50MB/s, you can use a sleep of `0.02`

Comment: In the future, please use the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on mouse-selected text to format as `code/data/requiredOutput/ExactErrMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: put a `sleep` value inside the loop? (If I understand your problem). Not a python use, so can't help with the exact syntax. Good luck.

Comment: I just wanted to confirm if the above code suggested is a right way to eat up memory, all I want to do is study /proc/pressure/memory. When I introduce sleep I do not see any spike in some or full value in /proc/pressure/memory. When I introduce sleep available memory goes up and then I also see a decrease the trend is not always rising. Without having stress tool how I can introduce a stress on memory ?@shellter @that other guy

Comment: @thatotherguy is much more likely to help with this. When I was doing performance testing, I wasn't aware of `/proc/pressure/memory` (I don't think SUN4 had that). Note that only first userid with an `@` will be pinged, and that names must follow the format supplied in the "hint" box that appears after you type `@[A-Za-z]...` (no spaces, all one word) AND having `?@` together hid your ping to me. Good luck!